# Get file from Android emulator sdcard

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I'm trying to get test coverage file from InstrumentationTestRunner but I have no idea how.

I tried:

> adb shell am instrument -w tomzi.net.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner -e coverage true -e coverageFile /sdcard/myFile.ec

How can I access files from sdcard?

> adb shell am instrument -w tomzi.net.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner -e coverage true -e

Where can I find that file in that case? It says it should be in /data//coverage.ec but I can't find it.

Test runs well and last 47 seconds, so file should be written.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create sdcard otherwise it will not read or write,
1st create sd-card
[create sd-card](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/create-sd-card-in-android-emulator-and.html)

2nd check like this
[your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680992/in-avd-emulator-how-to-see-sdcard-folder-and-install-apk-to-avd)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the SDCARD first otherwise you won't be able to read/write anything on it, please check this blog post:

http://www.androiddevelopment.org/2008/11/11/how-to-create-and-use-the-sd-card-with-the-android-emulator/

Comment: Done, so where can I find it?

I have sdcard.lock but it's not there as I thought.