# In AVD emulator how to see sdcard folder and install an APK to the AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have created an Android emulator (Android Virtual Device), but I am unable to find out the SD card I have built during creation of this.

How can I find the SD card and its content and also how to install APK files to the AVD?

Comment: Hi HIT. For what it's worth, I preferred @MCEmperor's edits to your question. It is unnecessary to embolden or italicise brand names and technical words unless either (a) you would specifically stress them when speaking them, or (b) in the case of italics, if your word needs defining for your audience. Neither is the case here. I wouldn't normally mention it, since it is minor, but if you are applying this approach elsewhere then it may just create editing work. You can find out more about when to apply these styles by referring to a writing style guide, if you wish.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

1. switch to **DDMS** perspective
2. select the emulator in **devices** list, whose sdcard you want to explore.
3. open **File Explorer** tab on right hand side.
4. expand tree structure. **mnt/sdcard/**

refer to image below[image]

---

To install apk manually:
copy your apk to to sdk/platform-tools folder and run following command in the same folder

```
adb install apklocation.apk
```

Comment: Do you know where the SD card is in Android Studio?

Comment: To open the DDMS perspective navigate to Tools | Android | Android Device Monitor . You can also click on the Android icon button from the toolbar. A new window will be opened with the DDMS perspective.

Comment: These days the location is at `/storage/emulated/0` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40437571/1245231

Answer (score 10):

I have used the following procedure.

**Procedure to install the apk files in Android Emulator(AVD):**

Check your installed directory(ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools), whether it has the adb.exe or not). If not present in this folder, then download the attachment [here](http://www.botskool.com/downloads/geeks/android/adb.zip), extract the zip files. You will get adb files, copy and paste those three files inside tools folder

Run AVD manager from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk and start the Android Emulator.

Copy and paste the apk file inside the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

- Go to **Start -> Run -> cmd**
- Type **cd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools”**
- Type **adb install example.apk**
- After getting **success** command
- Go to Application icon in Android emulator, we can **see the your
  application**

Answer (score 7):

These days the location of the emulated SD card is at `/storage/emulated/0`

Answer (score 5):

On linux sdcard image is located in:

```
~/.android/avd/<avd name>.avd/sdcard.img
```

You can mount it for example with (assuming /mnt/sdcard is existing directory):

```
sudo mount sdcard.img -o loop /mnt/sdcard
```

To install apk file use adb:

```
adb install your_app.apk
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

DDMS is deprecated in android 3.0. "Device file explorer"can be used to browse files.

Answer (score 3):

## Drag & Drop

To install apk in avd, just manually drag and drop the apk file in the opened emulated device

The same if you want to copy a file to the sd card

Comment: Are you sure this works? I was not able to get it the opened device register the drag-drop.

Comment: The simplest workaround, for those who just run the emulator from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Eclipse. You should switch to DDMS perspective from top-right corner  there after selecting your device you can see folder tree. to install apk manually you can use adb command

```
adb install apklocation.apk
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following procedure.

Android Studio 3.4.1

View>Tool Windows>Device File Explorer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

//in linux

// in your home folder .android hidden folder is there go to that there you can find the avd folder open that and check your avd name that you created open that and you can see the `sdcard.img` that is your sdcard file.

//To install apk in linux

```
$adb install ./yourfolder/myapkfile.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the usefile DDMS/File Explorer solution, for those that don't know, if you want to read a file you need to select the "Pull File from Device" button on the file viewer toolbar. Unfortunately you can't just drag out, or double click to read.