# Can we run android app in eclipse emulator by using the apk file

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I want to test an already existing android app with different AVDs of different API levels. I have the apk file but not the source code. Is there any way to install this app in emulator by just using its apk file?

Comment: You can find some detailed answers here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680992/in-avd-emulator-how-to-see-sdcard-folder-and-install-apk-to-avd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to use the **`adb install /path/to/your.apk`** command to install an app on a device or emulator. You can find the **`adb`** binary in the `platform-tools/` directory of your SDK installation.